# Error in MMQ2GIS what is going wrong here?

Tags: qgis-2.18, mmqgis

To make sure things go efficiently in this green service community I created a skeleton shapefile or two, based on copy's they could give me. I created structure/style's settings by creating new attributes and value map's. I also save this locally so I can load the style in the new shapefile.

Because they stil need to get working, there shapefile contains new objects but do not have the same structure/shapesettings.

Because they are the same in spatial relation I tried the MMQGIS, to merge these two layers into one. However when I try do this an "Error" occures.

**Keep in mind this in dutch: I cannot sadly translate this**

[image]

Comment: Do any of your vector layers happen to have the same name? It seems the latest MMQGIS version (2017.2.28) fails to start `Merge layers` function when there are layers with the same name in the `Layers panel`. Can you try either (1) change layer name to make all unique, or (2) install older version (2017.2.12)?

Comment: Another option, `Processing Toolbox | QGIS geoalgorithms | Vector general tools | Merge vector layers`, if it does not have to be MMQGIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have already figured out, but just to update; 
MMQGIS plugin (version 2017.5.14) has fixed this issue.

quote from changelog -

> Fix mmqgis_load_combo_box_with_vector_layers() so it can fill both QListWidget
>   and QComboBox and doesn't throw error in merge_layers. Add all layers and all
>   attributes options to search.
>   Fix space replacement with '+' so Google search works.

yay!